# IONIC: From MYSQL to MSSQL

Tags: php, mysql, ionic-framework, sql-server-2012

Am creating an ionic application using php, at the beginning I've linked the login form with a mysql database that I've created using wamp as a server and everything works fine!
then my boss saids that I have to change it  to another database which is on a Microsoft sql server, so I've linked the wamp server with MsSQL and the Connection with database on MSSQl established correctly

but I didn't know how to change the syntaxe on login.php

Here are the old and new cofig.php that works fine

(New config.php)

```
<?php
$serverName = "HAMDI-PC";
$connectionInfo = array ("Database"=>"MAINT","UID"=>"sa","PWD"=>"sql") ;
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
?>
```

(OLD config.php)

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "MAINT");
?>
```

And here is the (login.php) that works with mysql database

```
<?php 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

if(isset($_GET["username"]) && isset($_GET["password"]) ) {
    if( !empty($_GET["username"]) && !($_GET["password"]) ) {
        include"config.php";

        $username=$_GET["username"];
        $password=$_GET["password"];

        $query=" SELECT * FROM D_PROTUSERS WHERE PROT_User='$username' AND    PROT_Password ='$password' ";
        $result = $conn->query($query);

        $out="";
        if ($rs=$result->fetch_array()) {
            if($out != "") {$out .="";}
            $out .='{"PROT_User":"'. $rs["PROT_User"] . '",';
            $out .='"PROT_Password":"'. $rs["PROT_Password"] . '"}';
        }
        $out='{"recods":'.$out.'}';
        $conn->close();
        echo($out);
    }
}
?>
```

So please  I want to know what should I change to make it work at the new database'MSSQl) ,
I'll be thankful to everyone who will tries to help :*

Comment: Hi just check this out : https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/2204/mysql-to-sql-server-coding-differences/  . I'm sure you should be able to do it with this help.

Comment: Thank you dear
But it's not really helpful 
sitll  can't fix the problem

Comment: Try this: `"SELECT ALL FROM D_PROTUSERS WHERE PROT_User='$username' AND    PROT_Password ='$password' " `  and then could you echo your  $result please  like this : `echo"$result "; ` then show me what you get for the echo.

Comment: i've found a way thank you so much !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget about mysql, you're using ms sql.. so you have to use [sqlsrv](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php)

Here we go.

> config.php

```
$serverName = "HAMDI-PC\SQLEXPRESS";
$dbname = "MAINT";
$uid = "sa";
$pwd = "sql";
global $con;

$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,
                     "PWD"=>$pwd,
                     "Database"=>$dbname);

/* Connect using SQL Server Authentication. */
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false )
{
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

And

> login.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include"config.php";

    $username=$_REQUEST["username"];
    $password=$_REQUEST["password"];

    $query = " SELECT * FROM D_PROTUSERS WHERE PROT_User='$username' AND PROT_Password ='$password' ";
    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, array() , array(
      "Scrollable" => 'keyset'
    ));
    $num = sqlsrv_num_rows($result);

    if ($num > 0)
    {
      $_SESSION["valid_user"] = true;
      $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
      sqlsrv_close($conn);
    }
    else
    {
      echo "Login Failed: Connection could not be established.";
      exit();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Mànìkàndàn Thank you so much 
your code works right :D